# igraph - Issue with transparent edges

Tags: r, igraph

The following code creates and plots a graph with 4 nodes and standard normal edges:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
adjmat <- matrix(rnorm(16), 4, 4); adjmat <- 1/2 * (adjmat + t(adjmat)); diag(adjmat) <- 0
ig <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjmat, "undirected", 
                                      weighted = TRUE, diag = FALSE)
edge_col <- function(x, alpha) 
             ifelse(x > 0, rgb(0,0,1,alpha = alpha), rgb(1,0,0,alpha = alpha))

# this works fine
plot(ig, edge.color = edge_col(E(ig)$weight, alpha = 1))

# no edges show up in plot
plot(ig, edge.color = edge_col(E(ig)$weight, alpha = 0.9))
```

The color transparency is set using the opacity parameter `alpha` in `rgb`. Why do no edges show up when `alpha < 1`?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be working fine on my machine for any value of `alpha` (that is, I can see the edges and they have the appropriate transparency level).

Comment: Which version of `igraph` do you have on your machine? Plotting transparent points on a regular plot, say `plot(seq(10), col = rgb(1,0,0,0.5))` works fine for me, so I think it may be the version of `igraph` that's the problem.

Comment: igraph_1.0.1 for me.

Comment: Strange, I use the same version (on Windows).

Comment: I'm on a Mac, though I don't know if that should matter. What happens if you start a clean session and run only the code in your question? Do the edges still disappear whenever alpha < 1?

Comment: Yes, in fact I see the same problem on two different machines, both running 1.0.1 on Rstudio Windows.

Comment: On my Windows machine, I also cannot adjust the alpha-channel - either edges are displayed or not.

Comment: Actually, plotting the transparent graph works fine when I try it on a clean session. When I try to plot the same again, the edges disappear.

Comment: What about if you save the plot to a png or pdf?

Comment: Yes, that works fine. Thanks!

Comment: This probably does not have much to do with igraph, but more with whether you graphics device supports transparency.

Comment: @GaborCsardi my graphics devices (on two seperate Windows machines, both running `igraph 1.0.1` on Rstudio with MRO `3.3.0`) have no problems plotting transparent points on a generic plot, say `plot(seq(10), col = rgb(1,0,0, alpha = 0.5))`. The issue only appears while using `plot.igraph` with transparent edges.